# update XML file in a page Jsp

Tags: xml, spring, security

I use spring security and i have many roles in my database for example ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER so in my xml file named "spring-security.xml" i defin for each page wich role can see it :

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/les_statistiques*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/mise_a_jour*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/recherche*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/failLogin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logoff" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
    </http>
```

What i want to do is to have a page jsp where the administrator can chang the value of the parameter **access** . How can i do it? what should I use?

Comment: I don't know spring security enough to know how to do that, but changing the XML file won't help: the info it contains is read at startup, and held in memory. I also think it's a bad idea. Instead, use finer-grained roles, and assign roles to groups and users in the database, rather than changing which role can access a given pattern. For example, /les_statistiques should be associated to a role ROLE_STATISTIQUES. And the appropriate users and groups should then be assigned this role.

Comment: BUT ! the problem is that a user can have just one role not many roles for each page, and if the XML file is read at startup, after updating, i can make the administrator reload the application.